# Kernelled Regression

Tags: r, regression, machine-learning, kernel-trick

I am trying to implement Protocol 3 mentioned in the paper [On-line Prediction with Kernels and the Complexity Approximation
Principle](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1207.4113.pdf). I have written the following code in R using polynomial kernel:

```
library(MASS)

Data<- read.csv("https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/breast-cancer-wisconsin/wpbc.data",header = F,sep = ",")
X <- as.matrix(Data[,c(-1,-2,-34,-35)])
Y <-as.matrix(Data[,34])

poly.kernel <- function(v1, v2, p=2) {  

    (as.matrix(v1) %*% (as.matrix(v2))+1)^p
} 
KAAR<- function(x,y,a){
  x<-as.matrix(x)
  y<-as.matrix(y)
  N<-ncol(x)
  T<-nrow(x)
  yt <- NULL  
  Mt <- NULL 
  k <- NULL 
  pred<- matrix(0,ncol=1,nrow = T)
  for(t in 1:T){
    yt <- append(yt,0)
    Mt <- as.matrix(rbind(Mt,x[t,]))
    kt <- poly.kernel(Mt,x[t,])

    K <- poly.kernel(Mt,t(Mt))

    pred[t] <- t(as.matrix(yt)) %*% ginv(a*diag(1,t)+as.matrix(K))%*%kt
    yt[t] <- y[t]
  }
  return(pred)
}
KAAR(X,Y,0.5)
```

The code works, but the results are not so good. I am getting r-squared of `0.005629695`. Following is the plot of actual vs predicted[image] [image]

Can someone please review and comment?

Comment: What do you mean by "results are not so good"?

Comment: @PeterFlom I hope my question is more clear now.

Comment: Unless the numeric value of "index" is meaningful (e.g if it is an index of time) then a better graph would be a scatter plot with "actual" on one axis and "predicted" on the other.  I don't know much about the method you used, but whenever R squared is much lower than expected the two prime candidates are 1) Data entry problems and 2) Your theory just isn't right.  No one wants to hear the second, but it does happen.

Comment: Scatter plot (here index of time is used) shows they are too far from the line $y=x$. Maybe, something wrong with the theory.